# Codeigniter csrf token not in post array

Tags: codeigniter, http-post, csrf, codeigniter-3

When posting a form with a csrf token, `$this->input->post("csrf_token")` is empty.

I could post a duplicate csrf_token using another field name. But that looks a bit unnecessary.
Is there (another) way to get it?

__

All is done using AJAX. So first of all, a token must be requested, and is provided using a json template, populating it this way:

```
$data["json"] = array(
    "csrf_token" => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
);
```

Using that token, a ajax POST request is done, sending user login, password. If `?debug`is added to the request url, and the ENVIRONMENT is not production, the complete post request parameters are added to the json output. Like so:

```
if( !is_null($this->input->get("debug")) && ENVIRONMENT != 'production'){
    $debug = TRUE;
    $data["json"]["post"] = $this->input->post();
}
```

And I get:

```
"post": {
    "un": "test",
    "pw": "test"
}
```

Adding `$data["json"]["old_token"] = $this->input->post("csrf_token");`gives me `"old_token": null`

The Cross-site request forgery itself, works as expected: **no token, wrong token or expired token gives an error**. So Codigniter does receive the token as a supposed to. It seems to be removed from the post data.

Comment: Did you tried `ci_csrf_token` instead of `csrf_token`??

Comment: I tried, but still `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some poking around, I've found the answer. The security class removes the token from the POST array: `unset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name]);` (core/Security.php in `csrf_verify()` at line 234)

I won't change that line, to be sure the controller keeps functioning after updating Codeigniter.