# CSRF token value isn't defined in POST data in CI

Tags: codeigniter, csrf, codeigniter-3, csrf-protection

In View source I have following code

```
<form action="http://localhost/working/codeigniter/index.php/test.html" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name"    value="e44f21e60b55e940f05626b3b7b01fcb" />
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

But `$data = $this->input->post()`; is not giving me `csrf_test_name` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSRF token is removed from the post data by the security class.

see [this post for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607615/codeigniter-csrf-token-not-in-post-array)

Then it's all automatic: if the $config['csrf_protection'] is enabled, it's gonna be validated by the Input class and return an error if the token doesn't match.

Comment: ok thanks , but how we will validate token value , where token hash value has been stored in CI

Comment: Updated my answer